# getting 'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' on BinaryClassificationMetrics

Tags: pyspark, binary, confusion-matrix, data-science-experience

I was trying to get the binary classification report on pyspark and I ran into this error

***StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'***

Here is my code

```py
%%spark

from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
#from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
predictionAndLabels = test_pred.rdd.map(lambda Row : (float(Row['label']) , Row['prediction']))
metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
```

Also , Based on the documentation [a link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.html)! , apparently it does not support f1 measure and recall etc . Any idea why or how we can extract them without low level coding ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to go that deep.  Taking their example of the data from the binary from the documentation you linked and assuming your threshold is p=0.5 cutoff you can just do something like

```
# f1 = 2 · Precision · Recall/Precision + Recall
# precision = tp / tp+fp
# recall = tp / tp+fn

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

scoreAndLabels = sc.parallelize([(0.1, 0.0), (0.1, 1.0), (0.4, 0.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.6, 1.0), (0.6, 1.0), (0.8, 1.0)], 2)
df = scoreAndLabels.toDF()

threshold = 0.5

tp = df.where((col('_1')>=threshold) &(col('_2')==1.0)).count()
fp = df.where((col('_1')<threshold) &(col('_2')==1.0)).count()
fn = df.where((col('_1')>=threshold) &(col('_2')==0.0)).count()
precision = tp / (tp+fp)
recall = tp / (tp+fn)
f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

returns f1 = 0.75.